# How to create and install a powershell command package using chocolatey?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I have a few powershell commands in a script that I want to distribute to everyone on my team. This script may be updated and I would want an easy way for my team to update this script as well. Someone suggested Chocolatey which I have never used before. I found the following in the Chocolatey.org FAQ:

"What kind of package types does Chocolatey support?

Binary Packages – Installable/portable applications – This is 98% of the Chocolatey packages – most are pointers to the real deal native installers and/or zipped software.

**PowerShell Command Packages – Packages that have the suffix .powershell will install PowerShell scripts as commands for you to call from anywhere.**

Development Packages – Packages that have the suffix .dev. For instance dropkick.dev.

Coming soon – Virtual Packages – Packages that are like a category, and you just want one package from that category. Read more ..."

Does anyone have an example of using chocolatey to install a powershell script to the Path so that the commands in it can be executed from anyway on the machine? I am unable to find an example of how to do this online.

If this is an inappropriate use of chocolatey, please let me know and feel free to recommend an alternate solution.

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you have any questions for me?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [PowerShell Function Reference](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-reference), which has all of the different functions you can call. Then take a look, specifically, at the [`Install-ChocolateyPowershellCommand`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-powershell-command) helper. Here's [an example](https://chocolatey.org/packages/installwindowsimage.powershell) of a package that installs a powershell script as a command ([source](https://github.com/ferventcoder/chocolatey-packages/tree/04887fd7fbde467c723803dee4f5a3240c583752/manual/installwindowsimage.powershell)).